# PGF_2.10-CVS I lost the blue links when I compile the doc

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref

My method to build the  pgfmanual.pdf is :

```
$ cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/pgf co -P pgf
$ cd ~/pgf/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en
$ mkdir plots
$ TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make
$ TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make dist
$ TEXINPUTS=".:~/pgf//:" make dist
$ cd ~/pgf/generic/pgf/testsuite/mathtest
$ pdflatex mathtest
$ cd ~
$ make -f pgf/scripts/pgf/Makefile.pgf_release
```

The result is correct. Automatic cross references in codeexamples  are enabled, the links work but I lost the blue color for these links. The pgfmanual-pdftex.cfg file is unchanged . I work with MacTeX 2011 prerelease and pdflatex.

I put the files [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the link colors has been disabled by one of the pgf team (probably a matter of taste):

see pgfmanual-en-main.tex :

```
20  \usepackage{hyperref}
21  \hypersetup{%
22  colorlinks=false, % use true to enable colors below:
23  linkcolor=blue,%red,
24  filecolor=blue,%magenta,
25  pagecolor=blue,%red,
26  urlcolor=blue,%cyan,
27  citecolor=blue,
28  pdfborder=0 0 0,
29  }
```

Comment: Thanks Christian !! I updated ... 890 pages for 6.3 M It's a big pgfmanual now ! Interesting to see lua in pgfluamath and some lua code for the graphs !!